# how to call one model from another route

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

please i have a question. i have tried to implement this for more than four hours but it didn't work. I am working with `Node`, `express`, `mongoose` and `ejs` template
How do i call a model to fetch all the data inside it from another route file.

For example:

i have `Post` model and the `post.js`  `file` is inside `model` folder.

and i have `index.js` `router`, and the `index.js` file is inside `routes` folder

inside the `routes/index.js` file i want to fetch all the `posts` inside `Post` Model when home page is loaded so that i can display them on my `layout file`(landing page)

GET HOME PAGE AND RENDER POSTS ALONG

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const allposts = Post.find({})
  res.render('index', {
   allposts: allposts
  });
});
```

The reason i am taking this approach is because i want to display my newest post blogs on my layout file(landing page) but when i include the posts index file on my layout it says that my posts is undefined, so i have decided to take a different approach to accomplish this.
if you know how i can get this done, please help me or any other method that i can use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo queries are asynchronous. So when you return the response, the Post.find() query has not been completed. You can use callbacks, promises or async/await to control the flow.

```
// require Post model
const Post = require('../model/post'); 

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.find()
    .then(allposts => {
        res.render('index', {allposts});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: @dimitrisi really don't know how to thank you enough, i have been stuck with this problem for five days now and no one could give me a solution. i am more than grateful, thank you so much. i am feel with joy